# Hiding the 'help' menu from the ping command

Tags: php, windows, windows-xp, ping

I'm currently trying to ping a host in windows XP through PHP. At the moment, I was able to do so but the 'help' keeps showing whenever I try to ping a host from my machine, so I was wondering if there's a way to hide the 'help' menu in anyway.

This is the code I was able to run on XP

```
<br><input type='text' name='ip2'>
          <input type='submit' value='ping'>
          <?php

          $ip= "";
          $status="";
          $output="";

          function test_input($data){

            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
          }

          if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST"){
            if(empty($_POST["ip2"])){
                echo "IP must not be empty!";
            } else{

                $ip=test_input($_POST["ip2"]);

            }
          }
            $output=shell_exec('ping ' .$ip. '');
            echo"<pre>$output</pre>";


          ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First concern would be that help is showing up cause `PING` does not recognize the IP. I wonder if the command is just getting `ping  ` with no IP.  You could buffer the results and only display the portion you want.

Comment: @Twisty it is taking the IP before executing the    `ping` command

Comment: Also, why the double single quotes: `$output=shell_exec('ping ' .$ip. '');` ?

Comment: how do you know? your IF statement could fail and the command would still run but `$ip` would have a null value. Would echo the command before running it.

Comment: @Twisty That's for parsing, without the ''   there's a parsing error generated

Comment: That's what I did initially, I echoed the result of the IP before pinging it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to suppress the help. It should not display when running the command unless the command is run with no arguments. More: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Here is one way to run what you're doing:

```
<br />
<input type='text' name='ip2' />
<input type='submit' value='ping' />
<?php
$ip= "";
$status="";
$output="";

function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if(!isset($_POST['ip2'])){
    echo "IP must not be empty!";
} else {
    if(empty($_POST["ip2"])){
        echo "IP must not be empty!";
    } else{
        $ip=test_input($_POST["ip2"]);
        $output=shell_exec("ping $ip\r\n");
        echo"<pre>$output</pre>";
    }
}
?>
```

This ensures that all conditions are met before executing the `ping`.

If this still executes and displays the help text, we can look at the words and lines (using `explode()` or `strpos()`) and see if `Usage:` exists in `$output`. That would look like:

```
$output=shell_exec('ping ' .$ip. '');
if(stripos($output, "usage:") === false){
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
} else {
    $lines = explode("\r\n", output); // Explode output by end of line
    echo "<pre>";
    $suppress = true;
    for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++){
        if(stripos($lines[$i], "pinging") === true){
            // 1st line of ping response: "Pinging ..."
            $supress = false;
        }
        if(!$supress){
            echo $lines[$i] . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</pre>\r\n";
}
```